# Selección de submenú en selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Solicito su amable ayuda con Selenium. (Trabajo con WebDriver - java en eclipse) 
Mi caso es el siguiente: Mi aplicación es java con jsp y solo se ejecuta en internet explorer. Uno de mis steps es la selección de un submenú el mismo se abre con el evento onclick y se despliegan las opciones mediante una tabla. Pero al expandir el submenú no he sido capaz que el driver de selenium de click sobre uno de los submenús.

El código html que despliega el submenú es el siguiente (El que quiero seleccionar es "Nueva Carta Crédito") :

```
    <DIV id = "menudiv" style = "z-index:-100;position: absolute;height:0px;width:0px;display:none;">
<div id='lmoptions'  style="border-style: outset;font-size:10;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width: 100%;height: 5px;position: absolute;background-color: #88BBD9;" >
    <table id='lmoptionstable'>
        <tr onmouseover="parent.highliterow(this)" onclick="parent.clickModule('immenu','IM','V', this.children[0].innerText);parent.hidepopup();"><td><label style="font-size:10;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width: 120px;overflow:hidden;">Vista</label></td></tr>

        <tr onmouseover='parent.highliterow(this)' onclick="parent.clickModule('immenu','IM','I', this.children[0].innerText);parent.hidepopup();"><td><label style="font-size:10;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width: 120px;overflow:hidden;">Nueva Carta Crédito</label></td></tr>
        <tr onmouseover='parent.highliterow(this)' onclick="parent.clickModule('immenu','IM','CP', this.children[0].innerText);parent.hidepopup();"><td><label style="font-size:10;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width: 120px;overflow:hidden;">Preaviso Completo</label></td></tr>
        <tr onmouseover='parent.highliterow(this)' onclick="parent.clickModule('immenu','IM','A', this.children[0].innerText);parent.hidepopup();"><td><label style="font-size:10;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width: 120px;overflow:hidden;">Enmienda</label></td></tr>
        <tr onmouseover='parent.highliterow(this)' onclick="parent.clickModule('immenu','IM','N', this.children[0].innerText);parent.hidepopup();"><td><label style="font-size:10;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width: 120px;overflow:hidden;">Negociación</label></td></tr>
        <tr onmouseover='parent.highliterow(this)' onclick="parent.clickModule('immenu','IM','U', this.children[0].innerText);parent.hidepopup();"><td><label style="font-size:10;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width: 120px;overflow:hidden;">Actualización</label></td></tr>
        <tr onmouseover='parent.highliterow(this)' onclick="parent.clickModule('immenu','IM','W', this.children[0].innerText);parent.hidepopup();"><td><label style="font-size:10;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width: 120px;overflow:hidden;">Bandeja de Trabajo</label></td></tr>


    </table>
</div>
```

Hasta el momento he intentado con las siguientes opciones, pero ninguna ha sido efectiva:

Opción 1: Para este caso hice una validación donde encuentro que el elemento ‘el’ no es “cliqueable”

```
        WebElement table= driver.findElementById("lmoptionstable");
    WebElement el= table.findElement(By.xpath(".//tr/td/label[text()='Nueva Carta Crédito']"));
    el.click();
```

Opción 2:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement elementToHover = driver.findElement(By.id("lmoptionstable"));
WebElement elementToClick = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Nueva Carta Crédito']"));
action.moveToElement(elementToHover).click(elementToClick).build().perform();
```

Comment: Hola Angela. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. ¿Por qué *"ninguna ha sido efectiva"* ? ¿Puedes añadir más informacion? Mira [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: En qué línea falla? Desde obtener la tabla?

Answer (score 1):

Como la tabla que contiene los elementos `tr` posee un id, acceder a los elementos de esta es sencillo. Solo tienes que acceder a la tabla por su id (como lo estas haciendo) y después obtener la lista de elementos que esta contiene, a través de su etiqueta.

```
// Obtienes la tabla
WebElement elementToHover = driver.findElement(By.id("lmoptionstable"));

// Obtienes la lista de elementos que contiene la tabla
List<WebElement> elementos = elementToHover.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

// Si quieres puedes recorrer la lista completa de los elementos con
// un ciclo u obtener un solo elemento de la lista indicando su posición.

// Obtienes el elemento que se encuentra en la segunda posición, el 
// que contiene el texto "Preaviso Completo".
WebElement elemento = elementos.get(1);

// Haces click en el elemento
elemento.click();
```

Comment: He realizado la prueba @David pero no he conseguido solución, el error que me aparece es que no se puede dar click sobre el elemento.

Comment: Con cual driver estas usando Seleniun?

Comment: InternetExplorerDriver() de Selenium

Comment: Se ejecuta correctamente IE, se abre y muestra las acciones que estas realizando?

Comment: Si se ejecuta correctamente, mis steps llegan hasta la apertura del submenú pero no a la selección de la opción.

Comment: Trata de obtener el texto de un elemento `tr` para estar seguro de que se esta accediendo a los elementos.

Comment: Tienes razón @David no trae ningún valor con getText() algo me está faltando

Comment: Puedes mostrarme el código que tienes ahora?

Comment: Lo que hago antes de es dar click sobre el menú y luego agrego el código que me pasaste.

Comment: Muéstrame una captura de tu codigo

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer tienes métodos de JavaScript atrapando los clics, eso se solucionaría usando un objeto `Actions`, aunque veo que ya lo intentaste y extrañamente no funcionó. Como recomendación, revisa la funcionalidad con quien la desarrolló para que verifiques que el `hover` se hace al elemento con id 'lmoptionstable' y no al elemento 'lmoptions'. Además, cuando `Actions` no funciona, es recomendable hacer las actividades paso por paso, es decir, primero el `hover` con su respectivo `perform` y luego dar la instrucción `click`.

Otra opción que puedes intentar es usar `JavascriptExecutor` luego de que se muestren las opciones:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elementToClick);
```

También es recomendable usar "explicit waits" usando la opción `elementToBeClickable`, por ejemplo:
`WebElement elementoToClick = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td[text()='Nueva Carta Crédito']")));`